# npm start and other scripts do nothing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, electron

Until starting up my computer this morning the following worked:

```
npm run start
```

which would run my custom script in `package.json` and essentially boot up electron with react.

However now running the same command does absolutely nothing. The terminal just returns.

```
~/myapp > npm run start
~/myapp >
```

I have tried the following with and without step 3 and it didn't work.

1. Delete `node_modules`
2. Delete `package-lock.json`
3. Run `npm cache clean -f`
4. Run `npm i`
5. Try again.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled node.

My setup is:

```
~/myapp > node -v
v13.5.0
~/myapp > npm -v
6.13.4
```

and my `package.json` is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "...",
    "version": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "author": "...",
    "build": {
        "appId": "appname.app",
        "mac": {
            "icon": "build/icon.png"
        },
        "extraResources": [
            "./public/**"
        ]
    },
    "homepage": "./",
    "main": "public/electron.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.7",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.8.2",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
        "array-move": "^2.2.1",
        "cross-env": "^6.0.3",
        "electron-context-menu": "^0.15.2",
        "electron-is-dev": "^1.1.0",
        "electron-window-state": "^5.0.3",
        "react": "^16.12.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
        "react-dropzone": "^10.2.1",
        "react-pdf": "^4.1.0",
        "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
        "react-smooth-dnd": "^0.11.1",
        "typeface-roboto": "0.0.75"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "react-start": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts start ",
        "react-build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
        "react-test": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts test",
        "react-eject": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts eject",
        "electron-build": "electron-builder",
        "build": "npm run react-build && npm run electron-build",
        "start": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm run react-start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\""
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^5.0.2",
        "electron": "^7.1.7",
        "electron-builder": "^21.2.0",
        "wait-on": "^3.3.0"
    }
}
```

Note: I had to add `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` to the scripts to fix a bug in a dependency.

Can anyone please help?

EDIT:

I just created a completely new project to test the problem as follows:

```
npm init react-app testapp
cd testapp
npm start
```

and the problem persists.

Comment: Maybe `ignore-scripts=true` was set in .npmrc ? Try to run: `npm config set ignore-scripts false`

Comment: Thank you! I'm so stupid. I set this to true last night and had completely forgotten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably `ignore-scripts=true` was set in .npmrc

Run: `npm config set ignore-scripts false`

Comment: Yup...that happens in projects that have dependencies with security problems.